# Nodejs post not sending response

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I am trying to understand why an ajax response would be sent when outside of a function, but not within the function.  The response object is accessible within the function, but it will not send the actual response.  What would cause this type of behaviour?

```
app.post('/login', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
   if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);
   var password = JSON.stringify(req.body.password);
   var username = JSON.stringify(req.body.username);
   //res.send('Invalid');  //This sends a response

   login.login(username, password,function(err,content) {
       if(err){res.send('Invalid');} //This does not send a response
       else {
          agent_valid = content[0].valid; 
          if (agent_valid === 0)
          {
              console.log(agent_valid);  //agent_valid is appearing as 1 or 0
              console.log(res);  //res exists and is written to console
              res.send('Invalid'); //This does not send a response
          }
          if (agent_valid === 1)
          {
              res.send('Valid'); //This does not send a response
          }
       }
    });
 });
```

This is the javascript sending the post request:

```
ajaxRequest.send(JSON.stringify({username:username, password:password})); 
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.responseText == 'Invalid') {
        window.alert(this.responseText)    
    };
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.responseText !='Invalid'){
        window.alert(this.responseText)

    };
}
```

Comment: are you calling the  `login.login()` 's callback?

Comment: if you make the first line of the login function res.send('Invalid'); does it send (if statement validation)

Comment: It does not send if it is there either.

Comment: The login.login() callback is the anonymous function 'function(err,content)'